# Is it possible to reference another application via an environment variable in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, environment-variables

Here is the scenario.

I have application A, which is a add-on tool of application B (a third party product).  I need to install a file in a directory of application B during the install of app A (Using Visual Studio 2005).  I know the default directory location of app B, but the user could change that location during the install of app B.  App B also sets an Environment variable of its location.

Is there any way I can use the System Environment variable that shows me the location of App B in my Visual Studio 2005 Setup project for App A to install that file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as the environment variable is a system environment variable. If it is a user environment variable, the user deploying the app A and B should be the same for you to access that during the deployment of app B. You may use System.Environment class in C# to access the environment variables.

Comment: It is a system environment variable, I've updated the question to clarify that fact.  My question is how can I use the variable in the setup installation project so the file gets placed properly during installation.